# sql data export script, creating corrupt file

Tags: php, sql, excel, csv

Ok, so I have the following script that will export data from my database using php. 
Everything works fine, except when I try to open the file in excel, I get "file is corrupt".
I have used this script before, and I cannot figure out why it's not working. It may be a simple solution that I cannot see. Thanks in advance!

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM trans",$link);
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$csv_output .= $row['Field'].",";
$i++;
  }
}
$csv_output .= "\n";

$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trans",$link);
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
$csv_output .= $rowr[$j].",";
  }
$csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;

exit;
```

Comment: Can you open the file in notepad and show us the first couple or three lines please?

Comment: Try to open it in a simple text editor and see what you get, nano, gedit, vim...

Comment: This is the output, there are three rows: 
 TranID,date,cat,title,desc,amount,
1,05-09-11,texas,lkadsjf,asldkfja;lsdk,20,
2,05-09-11,bal,laksdf,;lakjsdf,30,
3,05-09-11,Eating Out,test,I went to wendys,15,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Content-type is incorrect. Try using this instead:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
```

Comment: Can you open the file in a text editor and show us the first few lines please.

Comment: This is the output, there are three rows in the table "trans":  TranID,date,cat,title,desc,amount, 1,05-09-11,texas,lkadsjf,asldkfja;lsdk,20, 2,05-09-11,bal,laksdf,;lakjsdf,30, 3,05-09-11,Eating Out,test,I went to wendys,15,

Comment: can you put that into the question please? The formatting is wrong so I can't read it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions here:

1. Have you considered using `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`? If possible, this is probably the best way to do it.
2. If you don't want to / can't use `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`, PHP has native functions for writing CSV output, that handles things like escaping for you. See the [fputcsv() manual page](http://us.php.net/fputcsv) for more info. There's some examples in the user comments showing how to output it directly.
3. Make sure you choose the correct delimeters, escape, etc. when opening up the file in excel